# PHP - Looping through a mutidimensional list of percentages

Tags: php, random, multidimensional-array, percentage

I am building a space-related game and do not know how to loop through my array of percentage "spawn" chances, to end up with one generated star with a certain size.

Example of how it must generate:

```
$star_chance = rand(1,100);
$star_size_chance = rand(1,100);
//loop through the list of stars here
//selected star - orange
    //loop through the size chances of star orange
    //selected star size = medium
```

1. Red, Orange and Yellow stars each have a spawn chance, only one can spawn at a time
2. For each spawned star there is a chance of what size it shall become
3. The equation needs to accommodate for possibly more stars or sizes

   ```
   $star_array = array(
   "red" => array(
       "spawn_chance" => "25",
       "size_immense_chance" => "50",
       "size_giant_chance" => "25",
       "size_large_chance" => "15",
       "size_medium_chance" => "5",
       "size_small_chance" => "4",
       "size_dwarf_chance" => "1"
       ),
   "orange" => array(
       "spawn_chance" => "50",
       "size_immense_chance" => "4",
       "size_giant_chance" => "15",
       "size_large_chance" => "50",
       "size_medium_chance" => "25",
       "size_small_chance" => "6",
       "size_dwarf_chance" => "0"
       ),
   "yellow" => array(
       "spawn_chance" => "25",
       "size_immense_chance" => "0",
       "size_giant_chance" => "6",
       "size_large_chance" => "25",
       "size_medium_chance" => "50",
       "size_small_chance" => "15",
       "size_dwarf_chance" => "4",
       )
   );
   ```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php should be of use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not be a problem like this:

```
$star_array;

foreach($star_array as $chances_array) {
  foreach($chances_array as $chance) {
    // do sth
  }
}
```

If you need the keys you can use:

```
$star_array;

foreach($star_array as $star => $chances_array) {
  foreach($chances_array as $chance_name => $chance_percentage) {
    // do sth
  }
}
```